# Trying to make a bot that sends a message for specific user ids

Tags: discord.py

So I'm trying to make a bot that sends a message when somebody with a specific user id sends a message, but when I use it, it ends up spamming the message for every *other* user id, excluding the specific one. Here's my code.

```py
@client.event 
async def on_message(message): 
  if message.author.id != 206883079837450241:
    await message.channel.send('example')
```

Comment: Do you know what `!=` does?

Comment: haha realized i was using != and not ==

Comment: Does `==` solve your problem then...

Comment: erm, nevermind. the bot still sends messages even though the id isn't mine. what do I do?

Comment: Repaste the new code in your question and double check if your ID is yours

Comment: uh, nevermind again, it works, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Switch the `!=` with `==`. `!=` passes True only if the message's author is not yours. `==` does the opposite.